# PHP sessions wont work? using variables on multiple pages

Tags: php, session, variables

What i want i that i can use a variable to use on multiple pages.
The only problem is, is that it doesn't work cause i did something wrong i believe.
After a couple of hours looking at it thinking what could be wrong i decided to post it here, so maybe you can help me.
My code:
login.php:

```
<?php
    if(empty($_SESSION['pass']))  { 
        echo "U bent niet ingelogt.";
        echo '<form action="index2.php" method="post">';
        echo 'Code <input type="text" name="code">';
        echo '<input type="submit">';
        echo '</form>';
    } else {
        redirect($url);
    }

    $url = "index2.php";
    function redirect($url)
    {
        if (headers_sent()) {
            die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="' . $url . '";</script>');
        } else {
            header('Location: ' . $url);
            die();
        }    
    }
?>
```

Index2.php:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    // error_reporting(0);

    $CODE = $_POST["code"];
    $_SESSION["pass"] = $CODE;
    if ($CODE == "testpassword") {
        echo "password correct";
        echo '<br /><a href="index.php">Index</a>';
    } else {
        echo "Password wrong";
        echo '<br /><a href="login.php">Login</a>';
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    // error_reporting(0);

    $CODE = $_POST["code"];
    $_SESSION["pass"] = $CODE;
    if ($CODE == "testpassword") {
        echo "password correct";
    } else {
        echo "Password wrong";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: When i log in, on login.php, and then i get redirected to index2.php(its says password correct). then when i go to index.php it says password wrong while it should be "password correct", since its the same variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `session_start()` on each page that uses `$_SESSION[]` variables.

Missing in first file.

Comment: I have added session_start(); to the first line, but now (with the same login.php as shown above) all i see is a white screen

Comment: You redirect to $url but $url is not set in the else part

Comment: Ahh i forgot that, now i will get redirected to index2.php, and its says password correct, but when i got the next page(index.php), it says password wrong.

Comment: When you click on the link to "index.php"? Clear..because there is no $_POST['code'] because you submit no formular, so $CODE will be empty in index.php

Comment: So how can i make sure  i can use the variable in the index.php?

Comment: In index.php you have to set $CODE = $_SESSION['pass']

Comment: So i have tried that, but now i get "syntax error, unexpected T_IF in.....line 5", line 5 is correct since its the same as the one i used in index2.php?....line5: if ($CODE == "testpassword") {

Comment: Have you added a ; after $_SESSION['pass']?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `session_start();` in login.php.

`session_start` is used to create or resume existing session. If you don't call it in your script, you can't use `$_SESSION` array.